# Artificial reduction of NADP into NADPH by means of an electrical current

Tags: molecular-biology

I've recently been attempting to artificially drive the formation of NADPH via the NADP reduction mechanism utilized by Ferredoxin-NADP Reductase in the Light-Dependent Reactions of Photosynthesis in plants. My goal is to reproduce the synthesis reaction *in vitro* only by means of an electric current.

Is there any way to replace the electron pair supplied by PSI *in vivo*, with one from a current going through a wire? Would conducting electricity through a solution of Ferredoxin, FNR, NADP, and a weak acid yield any desirable results?

Comment: It SHOULD work, theoretically. If it doesn't, try using strong acid (not so strong that it'd degenerate other chemicals) ;)

Comment: @another'Homosapien' Thank you for your answer! So you are fairly certain that simply conducting electricity through a solution of the chemicals would lead to the spontaneous synthesis of NADPH by the FNR enzyme? I have to conduct this experiment for a research project, and I would like to have confidence that my ideas would "work". Also, what is the most efficient way of detecting NADPH in an aqueous solution?

Comment: @another'Homosapien' So I don't have to "bind" ferredoxin to the metal electrodes, right?

Comment: I said it SHOULD work, not it WILL work. There could be some problem at any step. I am not expert in using biochemicals in vitro, so I can just say that yes, theoretically it is possible. Ferredoxin carries electrons from PS-I to NADP, and since PS-I is the only source of electrons there, so ferredoxin is attached to the membrane. But as electrons would move from one place to another in solution, ferredoxin need not be attached at electrode.

Comment: @TomD Would a 100mM solution of acetate produce a pH below 5? Also, would serial dilution do for the experiment, since 100 micromoles for the NADP is a bit too sparse for our lab equipment? I don't know if your setup would yield a significant result, either. Finally, I would like to know how you came up with your numbers regarding the concentration of the chemicals. Could you clarify a bit more? Thank you!